# How to use it->empty() in an iterator

Tags: c++

I want to use an iterator as a condition of a for loop, but when I define it, it->empty() always reports an error. I don’t know where the error is. When I change it to (*it).empty() It will also report an error later

The error is: the expression must contain a pointer type to the class, but it has type "char *"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string s("some string");
    for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end() && !it->empty(); it++)
    {
        cout<< *it <<endl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `it` points to a `char`, what's your intent to perform check `empty()` on it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `it->empty()`?

Comment: What do you think `it->empty()` would do if it worked? The iterator points to a single element, not the actual string. You could use `s.empty()` but it wouldn't make sense because in that case `s.begin() == s.end()` and the loop doesn't execute anyway.

Comment: `it->empty()` is only valid if dereferencing the iterator `it` yields an object that has an `empty()` member function.   In your case, a `std::string`'s iterator when dereferenced gives a `char`, and a `char` (like all basic types) does not have member functions, let alone one named `empty()`.    `

Comment: What is your assignment or exercise? Please [edit] your question to include the *full* and *complete* assignment/exercise, including any and all requirements and limitations. Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The error is pretty clear: there is no empty() method in type char *. Now it reaally depends on what you wanna check (space, end of string...empty char)

Comment: And perhaps what you're looking for is [`std::isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) to check if a character is a space?

Comment: Also, there is no concept of an "empty `char`" in C++.   A `char` (like an `int` or a `float` or most other basic types) is either uninitialised - in which case accessing its value, including testing its value, gives undefined behaviour - or it is initialised and has a value.    Either way, it is not "empty" - it exists, it occupies a location in memory, and (if not specified as `const` or `constexpr`)  it can be assigned a value

Comment: Thank you everyone, I understand, this sentence is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that you are trying to access a member function called `empty` through a non-class type object(a `char` type object in this case). You can change your code to look like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"some", "string", "is", "this"};
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end() && !it->empty(); it++)
    {
        cout<< *it <<endl;
    }
    
}
```

The above code works because this time we are using/calling the member function `empty` through a class type object(a `std::string` object in this modified example).

Also if you only wanted to know why you're having this error then i think the comments and my answer, answer that. If you have any other/further question then you can edit your question to add that.